# Using Selenium Webdriver with Meteor on DigitalOcean

Tags: node.js, meteor, selenium-chromedriver, digital-ocean, mup

I have a meteor app hosted on DigitalOcean, but when I try to start a new WebDriver instance with Selenium, it says it can't find the chrome binary. I've installed chrome remotely, I've tried setting the binary path manually, letting selenium use whatever the default is, everything I can think of, and it refuses to work. I am happy to provide any additional info is needed, but this issue would be on any meteor app deployed though mup to digitalocean.

Comment: Your Meteor app is running on DO and your Chromedriver is, too? Or is the chrome running on another machine? If on DO, how did you install it?

Comment: I installed it via the commandline that DO gives you. I acually tried installing it a bunch of ways, uncluding setting up an ssh tunnel for graphical access, and installing it like I would on any regular computer, and through the commandline in several different ways. Clean droplet each time